# SimpleAudioEngine Cocos2d Leaking Memory

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I am running Instruments and it indicates that the SimpleAudioEngine is leaking memory. The screenshot is attached. The memory leak is multiple times although the screenshot only shows one instance. 
[image]

Also, sometimes it points to the following implementation (my code):

```
-(void) preloadGameSounds
{
    // pre load the background sound 

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"farm_background_sound.mp3"];

    // pre load the game sounds 

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"chickenlayingegg.mp3"];

    // setup ding sound 
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"ding.caf"];

    // egg pop sound 
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"baloonpop.wav"];

    // preload applause sound 
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"applause.mp3"];

    // wrong answer sound 
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"wrong_answer_sound.wav"];

}
```

When changing the scenes I also unload the sound using the following implementation:

```
-(void) unloadSoundEffects 
{

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"applause.mp3"];
    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"wrong_answer_sound.wav"];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"ding.caf"];

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"chickenlayingegg.mp3"];
}
```

This memory leak is making the FPS of the game to go low and making game slower and slower!

Comment: Hey @azamsharp, have you found out a workaround? I met this same leak.

Answer (score 2):

From the [cocosdenshion FAQ](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:faq):

> **What should I retain/release?**
>
> SimpleAudioEngine, CDAudioManager and
> CDSoundEngine APIs are all accessed
> through a shared singleton instance.
> This is a common pattern that is used
> throughout Cocoa Touch and cocos2d.
> The shared instance should not be
> retained or released.
>
> If you need to completely shut down
> CocosDenshion and free all resources
> it was using then call the end method
> on the highest level API you are
> using. ***For example if you are using
> SimpleAudioEngine then just call
> [SimpleAudioEngine end]***.
>
> If you use CDSoundSource objects you
> must obtain them through one of the
> factory methods such as
> soundSourceForFile. The CDSoundSource
> that is returned is autoreleased, that
> means if you want to use it outside
> the scope of the current method you
> must retain it. If you retain a
> CDSoundSource you should release it
> when you are finished using it.

Answer (score 0):

are you using simulator to run the leak tools ? 
i encounter the same leak in simulator but not on device.
try using device to run the leak tools