# Cocos2d memory leaks : SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

Getting lot of memory leaks in [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) iphone game. I used these calls to play music and effect.

[image]

[image]

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]  preloadEffect:kSoundTap];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:kMusic_LaunchScreen] ;

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:kSound_GettingPowerUp] ;
```

Anything wrong or need to release anything? In iPad3 if I play for more time the lots of performance problems occurs...In instrument only these leaks are found. How can I solve this problem ?

Here is one other [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235123/simpleaudioengine-cocos2d-leaking-memory), but no accepted solution. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: could you open View/Extended Detail and inspect the call stack? is there anything related to your code for any of those reported leaks?

Comment: try  calling `[SimpleAudioEngine end]` after playing your sounds and check if instruments keeps reporting leaks. NB: this is just for the sake of testing and collecting some more info -- I am not suggesting  you do that to fix the leaks.

Comment: if I place these two line then crashes:   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:kSoundTap] ;
    
        [SimpleAudioEngine end];

Comment: `end` should be executed after your sounds played -- if you are interested in testing this. on the other hand, if it seems complex to you, you could simply create a test project and play the two sounds, checking with instruments if the leaks are there...

Comment: I just made one sample, put seperate button to end. But again leaks are same...

Comment: its fine...I can replace AVAudioPlayer with SimpleAudioEngine until they fix their problem. Bye

Answer (score 0):

Do not retain or release AVAudioPlayer objects. Instead your must `end` your session. From what I can tell from instruments in the second screenshot on the highlighted row the event is "release" but according to documentation AVAudioPlayer events should not be released (or retained).